# Error when creating a NGINX reverse proxy on docker and sending a request to website in another container

Tags: nginx, docker, proxy, reverse-proxy, vs-web-site-project

I am currently trying to create a NGINX reverse proxy server using docker that will accept a request from the web to the proxy server, then redirect the request to a container with the website I want to be online. So i currently have 2 containers, one for the Nginx reverse proxy, and another that contains Nginx with LEMP and my website files. For some reason I am continuously getting a 502 Bad Gateway Error. I've tested the website container separately (directly connecting to the web rather than passing through the proxy) and the website properly showed. In addition I've used 'wget' to test for connectivity in the terminal, and the website container connects properly from everywhere, but when trying to access the Nginx proxy container using 'wget' it also displays a 502 Bad Gateway Error. I'm pretty new to web dev so I appreciate any help, as I might have just missed something simple.

Nginx Reverse Proxy Configuration file

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

root /var/www/html;

index index.html index.php index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name 138.197.67.44;

location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_pass http://172.17.0.2:80;
    }
 }
```

DockerFile for Reverse Proxy

```
#############################################################
#Dockerfile for creating and configuring a Nginx Reverse Proxy
#Based in Ubuntu 16.04
##############################################################


#Set base image as existing image with nginx configuration (one shown above)
FROM nginxproxyr

#FileName + Author
MAINTAINER NginxProxy Javier

# Update the repository sources lsit RUN apt-get update
#NOTE EVERYTHING IS ALREADY INSTALLED IN BASE IMAGE USED; just required to       configure the image

#EXPOSE AND ASSIGN PORTS

#Expose default port
EXPOSE 80

#Give access to the system to reach the script that runs the entrypoint
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/startup.sh

#Default port to excecute entrypoint
CMD service nginx start
```

Command to run a container from image created by Dockerfile

```
sudo docker run -it -p 80:80 -d NginxReverseProxy
```

Comment: It would be useful to see the logs from the Nginx container.   
How do you start the LEMP container?

Comment: Also, you should not rely on the IP of the LEMP container being constant. Those internal IPs can change whenever the container is restarted.
For your simple testing you can use the deprecated [link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/#connect-with-the-linking-system) feature. But to move forward invest the time to learn the [network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/work-with-networks/) feature.  This is what is used by Docker Compose.

Answer (score -1):

When you have two containers I advise you to use docker-compose and make references through service not by ip. Now if you want to make a redirection you are advised to use this image which is quite simple to see how it works.

https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy

Comment: Yea that was my plan for the future as I've heard docker compose is much more useful. However, I've been stuck on this error for such a long time, I really want to try to figure out what's causing the mistake. Thanks for the response thou!

Comment: Try to remove de nginx sever name configuration to, maybe you fix the error.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: What are the ip's of the containers

Comment: it's in the proxy_pass. the container I am trying to connect to has ip of 172.17.0.2, while the nginx-proxy container has ip of 172.17.0.3

Comment: If execute "curl http://172.17.0.2" into nginx container, the app response?. If not maybe you forget expose the app container port.